# How to get a list of registered beacons from google for public app

Tags: android, google-beacon-platform

So I want to create an app that shows all the beacons on the map. I was thinking on using the proximity beacon api to get the list of the beacons. However this seems to be used for managing the beacons.

Is my assumption wrong? Are there any alternative API I can use without user authentication? I just want to read all the beacons registered with google from the app

Comment: Are these your beacons you want to display?  You must of course register them with Google to get them back in a list.  Are you saying you just want to fetch this list in an Android app without the app user having to log in with Google?

Comment: Yes, from what I understand, the account that registered the beacon has to login to get the beacons from proximity beacon api. And there seems to be no read only and no way to access it using an api key. Is this the right assumption? I am hoping that I am wrong and there is a way to get a list of beacons

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take a look at the beacons.list method (https://developers.google.com/beacons/proximity/reference/rest/v1beta1/beacons/list). The return value of this method will be an array of beacons that match your search criteria. The beacon objects contain a latLng object which you can use to place a pin for each beacon on a map.
To use the method you need an OAuth access token and this means that you need a login.
There are some method within the Proximity Beacon API that require only an API key (like beaconinfo.getforobserved), but the beacons.list method requires a higher level of authentication.